# Adding roles to users

Tags: users

I added some users to my site.

Is there a way to add roles to thousands of users  at the same time?

Thank you.

Comment: What are your selection criteria? Are you trying to add a role to all users?

Comment: Not all users. Just the ones I just added (They have no roles yet).

Comment: Hindsite is 20/20. It would have been better to define a Rule to add the role, triggered on 'After saving new user'. Then the roles would be created as you added the users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to install the [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and [Administration views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module. After that, go to the users management interface (admin/people), select the users and select "Change user roles".

PS 1: You can select users by role ***(1 on the attached picture)***

PS 2: If you need to select ALL of the users, just click the button "Select all xxx rows in this view" ***(2 on the attached picture)***

[image]

2/ For selecting only users without role:

You'll have to modify the Views who handle the display:

1. Go to **http:///admin/structure/views/view/admin_views_user/edit/system_1**
2. On the "Filter criteria" section, click on "User:Roles"
3. Check the "Expose operator" box
4. Save and go back to the user selection page
5. Select the 'Only has the Authenticated user role' on the "Role" dropdown

That should really do it now! :)

Comment: Select the users? Will it allow me to select like 5, 000 users at the same time? Presently I can only select 50 via admin/people. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. When you select all it will ask you if you want to include all entries in subsequent pages

Comment: It gives only 2 options for selection: Either the 50 rows on the current page or all the rows in the views

Comment: To select users without role, you'll have to modify the Views who is managing the display. Will upload new screenshots...